# OS X Server Wiki - How can I get the content of a wiki page to display on another wiki page

Tags: ios, blogs, wiki, osx-server

In just about any wiki server you can create a hyperlink to another page on the wiki. How can one create a window that pulls the other page's content into my page?

I can add a HTML Snippet with an iframe but it pulls an entire page not just the content?

The code for the javascript behind the page is not obfuscated but it seems to use Prototype and I don't understant it?

Has anyone had any experience with this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done reliably, one can create iframes and whitelisting the domains it points to but it just pulls the full page into a small window. It's completely unusable.

What I was looking for is called an "inclusion" or "transclusion" and OS X Server does not have the feature that is apparently standard in MediaWiki and has been for years.

More info here:
[Wikis - Is there a wiki in which one can create, within a page, "windows" (partial frames) to other pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939105/wikis-is-there-a-wiki-in-which-one-can-create-within-a-page-windows-parti/26896832#26896832)