# Wikis - Is there a wiki in which one can create, within a page, "windows" (partial frames) to other pages?

Tags: iframe, wiki

In a "classic" wiki application one creates pages and uses hyperlinks inside the content of the pages to link them together in a meaningful way.

Is there a wiki that allows one to "pull" content from another page into your own? (as in create something similar to an HTML snippet that shows the content of another page, inline with the content on your own page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this feature is called creating a page "inclusion" or "transclusion" essentially instead of linking to a page, it pulls the content of that page into the one you're in.

MediaWiki has it, wagn.org has it and a lot of others too.